# How to pass Isolated Directive Values from directive to div

Tags: angularjs

Here i wrote simple Isolated directive for showing x And Y values

```
app.directive('meassageFunction', function () {
    return {
       templateUrl: '/Html/IsolatedScope/ISolatedDirective.html',
       scope: {
           X: '@',
           Y:'@'
       }
    }
})
```

**HtmlPage**

```
  <div meassage-function X="Md" , Y="Ghouse">

</div>
```

Comment: you don't need the comma between the `x` and `y` attributes in the directive. Also you are calling the directive "isolate-function", but you have defined "message-function"

Comment: Where <div isolate-function x="Md" ,y="Ghouse"> This is Even no use

Comment: @JHECT could u plz verify now

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: ok @Jhecht tq soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of typos in your work, which was interfering with what you were trying to do.

Please be aware that scope variables are case-sensitive (x is not the same as X), and that using the directive you define is *super* important.

```js
angular.module('thing',[]).directive('messageFunction', function () {
    return {
       template: '{{x}} {{y}}',
       scope: {
           x: '@',
           y:'@'
       }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="thing">
  <div message-function x="Hello" y="World">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: weni try as <div meassage-function x="Hello" y="World">
   {{x}} {{y}}
</div>
Why x And y values not assign

Comment: They are assigned to your scope.